# How do I display a picture in the CXGrid integer column?

Tags: delphi

I have a TcxGrid component to show data of a SQL Server table.
How do I display a picture in the CXGrid integer column?
The cells in this column can only be 0 or 1.

if integer column cell value = 0 then;
cximagelist.picture index = 0
else 
cximagelist.picture index = 1

[image]

Comment: You could try a ImageComboBox column and set all the items' Description to `''`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a ImageComboBox column:

```
procedure Test(ACol: TcxGridColumn);
var
  props: TcxImageComboBoxProperties;
  i: Integer;
  item: TcxImageComboBoxItem;
begin
  ACol.PropertiesClass := TcxImageComboBoxProperties;
  Assert(ACol.Properties is TcxImageComboBoxProperties);
  props := TcxImageComboBoxProperties(ACol.Properties);
  props.Images := YourImages;
  for i in PossibleIndices do
  begin
    item := props.Items.Add;
    item.Description := ''; // or IntToStr(i)
    item.Value := i;
    if i = 0 then
      item.ImageIndex := 0
    else
      item.ImageIndex := 1;
  end;
end;
```

You could probably do most of the above visually with the form designer.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this quite simply, as follows:

1. Add a column to the grid to display the image  and set its `Properties` value to `Image`
2. At run time, load two bitmaps, `BM1` and `BM2` with the bitmaps you want to display.
3. Add code to the new column's `OnCustomDrawCell` as shown below.

Code:

```
procedure TForm1.cxGrid1DBTableView1Column1CustomDrawCell(Sender:
    TcxCustomGridTableView; ACanvas: TcxCanvas; AViewInfo:
    TcxGridTableDataCellViewInfo; var ADone: Boolean);
var
  BM : TBitMap;
  ARect : TRect;
  I : Integer;
begin
    ARect := AViewInfo.Bounds;

    //  In the next line, 2 is the index of my integer column which 
    //  contains the value which deterimnes the image to display.

    I := AViewInfo.GridRecord.Values[2];
    if I = 0 then
      BM := BM1
    else
      BM := BM2;
    ACanvas.Draw(ARect.Left, ARect.Top, BM);
    ADone := True;
end;
```

Of course, if you don't want to display the integer field's value in the grid, you can simply delete its column or set its `Visible` property to `False`.